# JUnit 4 @Test annotation not taken into account when filtering by tags

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

When I try to run tests with tag filtering, only those marked with @Test from JUnit 5 are executed but not those marked with @Test from JUnit 4.

The point is that if the filtering expression is "!slow", it actually executes tests without the tag "slow" regardless which @Test annotation is used. But when I filter with the expression "slow", tests with this tag won't be executed if they have the @Test from JUnit 4.

I know I could change to the new annotation when adding a tag but it would be nice not to have to do that for the tests I already have.

I have this imported into my pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the test I am trying to run is

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
public class Test {
  @org.junit.Test
  @Tag("slow")
  public void test() {
    assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean you have several versions of junit in a single project? why?

Comment: Because I have added JUnit 5 today and @Test annotations are in different packages. That means I would have to go to every single test class to change the import statement. That's something I don't want to do.

Comment: IMHO it's okay to have JUnit 4 and 5 in the same project, when 5 was added to an existing project and you don't want to migrate all test classes at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 annotations in the same test. So your approach *will not work*. A solution might be to migrate these tagged tests to JUnit 5.

Background: The JUnit Platform uses different test engines to discover and execute tests. The junit-vintage-engine can handle tests written against the JUnit 4 API, where test methods are annotated with `@org.junit.Test`. The junit-jupiter-engine can handle tests written against the JUnit Jupiter API (commonly known as JUnit 5), where test methods are annotated with `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. Each engine only has knowlegde about their discovered test methods. The junit-vintage-engine doesn't have any behaviour for JUnit Jupiter annotations, so these annotations are simply ignored.